# Correct return type for the operator ++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a List and Iterator classes (our homework, we should implement our own list in stl style).
I have a question about the `++` operator.
In my implementation, the `++` does not return anything:

```
void operator++();
```

But a friend of mine implemented it like this:

```
Iterator& operator++();
```

I tested both of them, and it seems both of them work. But I believe there must be some big difference. But I am a newbie to C++ language. So I can't see it. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: ahh. it is c++ ^^. I always regard c and c++ as the same ^^. Sorry I am a real newbie

Comment: You should have the object return a reference to itself. So that you can do `myArray[i++]`, for example.

Comment: Bear in mind that you are implementing the *prefix* `operator++`. There is also a *postfix* version with different semantics.

Comment: @Dave except that the postfix operator should return a value.

Comment: @Dave Actually, the no-argument version is pre increment :)

Comment: @juanchopanza oops, you're right; `myArray[++i]`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common convention here is that overloaded operators should resemble ordinary ones.
For example, you can:

```
int x = 5;
int y = ++x;
```

So your iterators really should be usable in the similar context:

```
Iterator i = smth.begin();
Iterator j = ++i;
```

Your friend's version allows this.

There's also an old C joke:

```
++i = 0;
```

So yes, your `operator ++()` should return `*this` as an lvalue to allow this kind of stuff so the return type is `Iterator&` and not `Iterator` or `const Iterator&`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that your friend's version can be called in forms like

```
// loop that skips the first element
while (++it != end)
    // perform operation
```

where `it` is some iterator. Library functions and client code may depend on this, so always return `*this` from an overloaded `operator++`. All standard library iterators work this way and so do the pointers on which they are modeled.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that his operator can be used as if the iterator was a pointer, while yours cannot. With pointers, you can do this:

```
char *p1, *p2;
...
p1 = ++p2;
```

For this to work with iterators, the `++` operator must return the value before (or after) the increment, depending on the pre- or post- position of the operator. Your implementation does not do that. Although it is technically OK, the resultant operator is not as functional, so it is a good idea to change your implementation to return a value.